# How to run .exe file with various input files and one output file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an abc.exe file which uses 3 input text files say p.txt q.txt and r.txt and generate z.txt as an output file.

This is working fine in Linux but how to do it in MATLAB. I ran it with system command as:

```
status = system('abc.exe p.txt q.txt r.txt z.txt')
```

and

```
status = system('abc.exe ' 'p.txt ' 'q.txt ' 'r.txt ' 'z.txt')
```

In both cases, it does not generate z.txt and value of status is not zero.

How to rectify this ?

Comment: What did you enter into the terminal to run the exe on linux?

Comment: @sebastian: I dout there is a `C:\` on a linux OS, at least this way.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run

```
[status,cmdout] = system('abc.exe p.txt q.txt r.txt z.txt')
```

and tell us the resulting values of both `status` and `cmdout`. Maybe `cmdout` will give some useful error message. Some possible things that could go wrong is that `abc.exe` is not in the path, or that some environmental parameter is not set.